# Simple Notification for row insertion in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-sns

I have created a custom error log table in Redshift.

In which rows are inserted when any error occurs in my stored procedures.

Is there a way to get a notification like SNS whenever a new row gets inserted in that error table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no capability in Amazon Redshift to trigger events on row insertion.

Comment: Does this still apply? Did they come with any other update? I would have thought this would be a common use case